# decimal conversion using 5 bit two's complement

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, decimal, twos-complement

i am asked to show the calculation of 11+6 using 5 bit two's complement. i find some rules confusing but have come up with the answer as shown below. please let me know if it is correct or what needs to be done if it is wrong.

two's complement of 11 is
01011
two's complement of 6 is
00110
now adding them using carriers if required:

01011 -----11 in binary
00110  -----6 in binary
10001  ---total
which in decimal is 17. is this the correct method of working out??? because my result in binary shows 10001. isn't 10001 supposed to mean -1 because the first bit in two's complement is a sign bit. please help me solve this if it is wrong. thanks for your help.

Comment: No, 10001 is not supposed to mean -1. Did you look up what two's complement is?

Comment: i have done a lot of research. 10001 gives me 17 in decimal but according to two's complement, isn't the first bit supposed to be the sign bit which in this case is a 1 and from what i know, 1 means a negative magnitude. but the result surely can't be -1. so i tried inverting them since the result was a negative one. inverting 10001, gives 01110 which would give 14 but again that isn't the correct answer. i really am lost with this one.

Comment: To get the two's complement negation (often simply called "two's complement" .. or just "negation"), you invert the number and add one (equivalently, subtract one and invert). In this case, -10001 = 01111, which is 15, so 10001 is -15. To confirm, add 15, and observe that you get zero.

Comment: sorry  i forgot to mention the increment part (+1) but it still gives the wrong answer. it just doesn't seem to give 17 which would be the only correct answer.

Comment: 10001 is obviously already 17 without using any funny interpretation of it. You'd simply be treating it as unsigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain how this works. You know that 1 is represent as `00001` in 5-bit binary representation. To get -1, a known method for (2's complement) is to :

1. Invert all bits, which means `11110`.
2. Add 1 to the previous result which lead to `11111` equals to `31` in decimal base (unsigned).

Thus, `10001` is not equal to -1.

Now, let's take 11 (base 10) as an example. We know that 11 equals to `01011`.

1. Invert all bits => `10100`
2. add 1 => `10101` which equals to 21 in unsigned mode or -11 in signed mode.

You can then deduce that `10001` is -15 in signed mode or 17 in unsigned mode.

Also be careful, a signed 5-bit integer is bounded from -16 to 15. An unsigned 5-bit Integer is bounded from 0 to 31. **In your case, the answer is 17 which means it's an unsigned integer or -15 as a signed integer**.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: yep, i get what u mean but i am supposed to work with 5 bit two's complement using the first bit on the left as a sign bit. as we know 11+16 is 17 but the result given 10001 is the outcome of an error which is overflow. we can tell this simply because the magnitude of the sum which was supposed to be 17 has exceeded the limits/ range of the representation and has produced an error and as we know, the range of 5bit two's complement representation is -16 to 15. it produced an overflow error. would that be acceptable as a result?? because we simply can't represent 17 in a 5 bit system with a sign

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Take a look at my edited answer. You should understand.

Comment: thanks a lot. that cleared things up. i'll give 10001 as my answer in the case off unsigned integer.

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent if my answer helps you, don't forget to mark it as 'accepted answer' by checking it.